# Puppet inline template with puppet:// in URL

Tags: puppet

In my Puppet module, I have something like this:

```
file {'myfile':
  ensure => 'file',
  path => '/whatever/myfile',
  content =>  inline_template(file(
    "puppet:///modules/my_module/templates/${domain}/${::hostname}_myfile.erb",
    "puppet:///modules/my_module/templates/${domain}/myfile.erb"
  ))
}
```

And my spec looks like:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'my_module' do
  context 'with defaults for all parameters' do
    it { should compile }
  end
end
```

If try to run it, I get:

```
Failure/Error: it { should compile }
  error during compilation: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find any files from puppet:///modules/my_module/templates/dev.contaazul.local/myfile.erb, puppet:///modules/my_module/templates/dev.contaazul.local/myfile.erb at /home/carlos/Code/Puppet/modules/my_module/spec/fixtures/modules/my_module/manifests/init.pp:48:33 on node becker.local
```

Obviously, it cannot find any of the ERB templates. If I replace the `puppet://` part for `/home/carlos/Code/Puppet/` (where the code actually lives), it passes, but in production it is `/etc/puppet/`, so, it will not work.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RI Pienaar has released a [code snippet](http://pastie.org/666728) for a function with this behavior. You will need to copy this code into a file in one of your modules at the path `lib/puppet/parser/functions/multi_source_template.rb`.

Once you do that, you should be able to use it like so:

```
file {'myfile':
  ensure => 'file',
  path => '/whatever/myfile',
  content =>  multi_source_template(
    "my_module/${domain}/${::hostname}_myfile.erb",
    "my_module/${domain}/myfile.erb"
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As to *why* the original approach doesn't work: URLs are usually used with the `source` property only and transferred to the agent as is. The agent consumes the URL and makes an according request to a Puppet fileserver (which is just another master).

The `file` function on the other hand (as used here with the `content` property in conjunction with `inline_template`) will not process URLs and expects local paths instead.

All that being said, the issue could possibly have been side-stepped by specifying both the paths for the test box and the production system, with the latter just acknowledging that `/home/carlos` is missing. But that would have been far from a clean solution.